# App crashes loading database at the first run

Tags: java, android, json, database, sqlite

In my app, I'm using a service to get data from JSON and then save it in the database.

when I run the app on a new device it crashes **without any error**!

But when I comment out the code that is for loading into TextViews, It runs perfectly. After that, it just works normally even when I bring back the code to feed the TextViews.

**update:**
The service that is for feeding database doesn't run until I comment out the codes for feeding TextViews.

The code to feed the TextViews:

```
//this service contains JSON to DB code
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetdataService.class);
startService(intent);

cursor = DBOps.Ops.getTheOne();
cursor.moveToNext();

//app crashes at this line    
wordText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.TITLE)));
phonetic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.PHONETIC));
meaningText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.MEANING)));
exampleText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.EXAMPLE)));
```

Method to get an item:

```
public static Cursor getTheOne(){
    return db.query(DBContracts.Word.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            DBContracts.Word._ID + " DESC LIMIT 1"
    );
}
```

Comment: Please provide the crash logs - and there need to be an error mentioned somewhere in the logs

Comment: @WarrenFaith That's the point. There's no error!! nothing happens in Android Monitor!

Comment: There is no crash without traces in logcat... I think your . cursor is null

Comment: @Bruno No cursor is fed, I've checked.

Comment: Are you sure your db contains the column `DBContracts.Word.TITLE` ? I'm sorry but without log trace, it will be difficult to help you

Comment: As Bruno said, there is not crash without an stacktrace in your logcat. Simple basic VM handling. Have you tried to break at that line with a debugger and investigate what values your variables have?

Comment: How do you know app crashes on that line if there is no stack-trace?

Comment: @Bruno I understand it's complicated for me too! and yes, I'm sure about DB fields because it works when I comment out the DB related lines at the first run.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Yes I've tried. it leads to another file when I get to that line and then just stops.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon When app is starting, it shows a dialogue saying "Close the app."

Comment: Stop at that break point, to not go further and check what calls you do and ad them to your "watches". There you can see what they return before you really execute the line. So watch all those calls: `cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.TITLE)`, `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContracts.Word.TITLE))` and check what value `wordText` and `cursor` have.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I did it, The weird thing is when DB related codes are NOT commented out, the service that feeds DB with JSON doesn't run! So it has to be null, although it's not shown as null in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider examining the stacktrace when experiencing crashes.

But from your description: crashes on first run, works on later runs - this suggests that there's no data on the first run but on later runs the query returns some data.

`cursor.moveToNext()` returns a boolean value that is true if the move succeeded i.e. there is some data. You should always be checking cursor `moveTo...()` return values. The crash itself is because of `Cursor#getString()` on an invalid row.

Comment: Yes, I found out that my database is empty. the problem is, that the service that feeds the database, doesn't run until I comment out the code that is for feeding TextViews! And the code to trigger service is above the codes for feeding TextViews.

Comment: Service is running in background thread, so task of feeding to DB could run after showing data in TextView. You should check if the service task is finished.

Comment: @sso.techie I brought my JSON code into my MainActivity and put it in a method. But still, this method doesn't run until I comment out DB stuff! I'm frustrated.